# PHP Header / Login / I have header issues and I am hoping someone can assist

Tags: php

I have a lot going on in my header so I am hoping it is makes some sense. My Header does not render at all. The only part that shows up is the loginfrom2.inc.php I was wondering if anyone can let me know what is wrong

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
 <html>
 <head>
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css">
<style type="text/css">
.headerfont {
color: #FFF;
}
</style>

<?php
/*Login Logout*/
if(isset($_SESSION['currentMember'])) {
$currentMember=unserialize($_SESSION['currentMember']);
?>
</head>


<body>
<table width="764" height="97" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr valign="top">
<td width="248"></td>
<td width="100%" background="img/faddedbanner3.png"> <img src="../img/star3.png"  width="94" height="104" alt="Star"> <span class="headerfont" align="center"><strong>The    Unofficial Bank of Mike</strong></span></td><td background="../assign4/img/faddedbanner3.png"></td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>

<div id="logout">
<span id="user_session">VALUED CUSTOMER: <strong>
<?=$currentMember->firstname?>
<?=$currentMember->lastname?>
</strong></span>
<a id="logout" href="<?=URL_ROOT?>logout.php" title="logout">LOGOUT</a>


<?php 
}else{
require_once('loginform2.inc.php'); 
}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

//////////////////////////////////////////
This is my Loginform2.inc.php You can see the include statement above

```
<div id="login_form">
<form id="login" method="post" action="processlogin.php">
<p>
<label for="emailaddress">E-Mail Address:</label>
<input type="text" name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" size="15">
</p>
<p>
<label for="password">Password: </label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="email" size="15">
</p>

<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="login_submit" value="Login"></p>

</form>
</div>
```

///////////////////////processlogin.php

```
     /*start session*/
session_start();
$_SESSION['currentMember'] = serialize($currentMember);
```

note the screen shots of my my web page

[image: with image correct header without correct header]

Comment: have you tried the w3c validator? firebug? error console?

Comment: wow .. html4.01 transitional in year 2011

Comment: Is that really all there is in processlogin.php? Shouldn't it at least redirect you back to the main page? When you see the blank page, what is the URL in the address bar of your browser?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
/*Login Logout*/
if(isset($_SESSION['currentMember'])) {
$currentMember=unserialize($_SESSION['currentMember']);
?>
```

Move that block to at least be inside the `<body>` tag.

When `$_SESSION['currentMember']` is not set, the `<head>` element is never closed.

You also shouldn't be putting anything between the last `<tr>` and closing `</table>` tag. Your HTML is a bit of a mess.

---

Here's how you should probably structure it

```
<?php session_start() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- link / style elements, etc -->
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <!-- table contents -->
    </table>
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['currentMember'])) :
          $currentMember=unserialize($_SESSION['currentMember']); ?>
        <div id="logout">
            <!-- etc -->
        </div>
    <?php else : require_once 'loginform2.inc.php'; endif ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 If it branches to the `else`, the `<head>` tag is never closed, so you won't see any output.

Comment: I have read several time that the <head> tag is not closed.  But it right after I finish my first php tag.

Comment: I am blind tonight so I am at a loss

Comment: You also shouldn't be putting anything between the last <tr> and closing </table> tag. Your HTML is a bit of a mess. (agreed)=========================  I have moved the data from <tr></table> to just after those two tags uploaded and it did not work.

Comment: @Michael You're still inside the _true_ branch of the if when you close the head tag. So if `if(isset($_SESSION['currentMember']))` is false, the head doesn't get closed.

Answer (score 0):

**First move that `if` block inside your `body` tag, as others have suggested.** That means replace this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['currentMember'])) {
$currentMember=unserialize($_SESSION['currentMember']);
?>
</head>
<body>
```

With this:

```
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['currentMember'])) {
$currentMember=unserialize($_SESSION['currentMember']);
?>
```

If that doesn't fix it, take a look at this line:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['currentMember'])) {
```

It checks if `$_SESSION['currentMember']` has a value other than NULL. If not, loginform2 is displayed instead of your header. I can't see anywhere in the code you've pasted where `$_SESSION['currentMember']` is being given a value.

I'm guessing that it should be set in processlogin.php once a user successfully logs in. Perhaps some part of the login process is broken.

Comment: More likely is because the `<head>` isn't closed and there's no `<body>` tag, the login form is never visible in order to login.

Comment: I have posted my process login:  This where I start my session for in my processlogin.php

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it clearer what the others are suggesting. You MUST move the `</head>` and `<body>` tags above the PHP tag before anything will work. Please confirm that you have done this, then we'll see if there are any remaining problems.

Comment: @Michael, you also need to add <?php session_start(); ?> at the very top of the first file.